# DockerToolbox for win7 service unavailable error

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-toolbox

Initially got the error when running `docker ps` on CMD

```
An error occurred trying to connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v
1.23/containers/json: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the fi
le specified.
```

Followed the steps [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/22338)

```
C:\Users\kkk>docker-machine start default
Starting "default"...
Machine "default" is already running.

C:\Users\kkk>docker-machine env default
SET DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
SET DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.100:2376
SET DOCKER_CERT_PATH=C:\Users\kkk\.docker\machine\machines\default
SET DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=default
REM Run this command to configure your shell:
REM     @FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker-machine env default') DO @%i

C:\Users\kkk>docker-machine env --shell cmd
SET DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
SET DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.100:2376
SET DOCKER_CERT_PATH=C:\Users\kkk\.docker\machine\machines\default
SET DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=default
REM Run this command to configure your shell:
REM     @FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker-machine env --shell cmd') DO @%i

C:\Users\kkk>@FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker-machine.exe env --shell cmd')
 DO @%i
```

Now when I try `docker ps` again I get the following error

```
An error occurred trying to connect: Get https://192.168.99.100:2376/v1.23/conta
iners/json: Service Unavailable
```

Note: The machine is behind a corporate proxy

Answer (score 1):

If you are behind a corporate proxy, check if your `NO_PROXY` env variable is correctly set to avoid `192.168.99.100`